Enabling queries conditionally in react-query
I am using react-query hook for data fetching. I have some filters (Playground). I want to call the api only when the applied filters are valid. I am using enabled property to conditionally fetch. But my concern is, I have passed a function to enabled property which would be executed on every re-render. So, if I click on Re-render button, even though my filters was not changed, but the isFiltersValid function is called. In this example isFiltersValid is not a heavy computation, but what if it was a heavy computation function.
In case, if I just use useEffect, my code would look like:
  useEffect(()=>{
    //  here `isFiltersValid` is called only when filters change and not on every re-render
    if(isFiltersValid(filters)){
       queryFn()
    }
  },[filters])

How can I stop executing the isFiltersValid when filters are not changed. I can either memoize the result of isFiltersValid or can have a state which tells whether the status is valid or not and then I can pass that value to enabled. But is there any other approach without useMemo or using a state?

it is ok to recalculate the isFiltersValid on every rerender. And when and only when the computation became expansive you can memoize. It is a bad practice to pre-optimize your code as it can became slower and hard to maintain !
so you can just put it in the useQuery
const { data: response } = useQuery({
     queryFn: yourQuery,
     queryKey: yourKey,
     enabled: isFiltersValid(filters)
})


enabled-as-a-function is a relatively new feature, and it’s not optimised like functions for data transformation (e.g. select). There’s very likely no need to optimise a function that checks if some input to the queryFn is valid.
Really, this is very likely a tiny fraction of the complete javascript execution that happens in your code overall. People usually overestimate how much they can “save” here. If this is an “expensive” operation, like 500ms, you have a problem anyways because if the user changes filters, you need to re-run it - that’s bad. Don’t minimize the re-computations, fix that the execution itself is slow, then you can execute as often as you want and it doesn’t matter anymore.
That said, if you really need to optimize this - use a caching function. memoize-one is a popular choice (11 million downloads per week) which remembers the last invocation:
const memoizedFiltersValid = memoize(isFiltersValid)

then, use this function in enabled:
enabled: () => memoizedFiltersValid(filters)


You can handle this by creating a custom hook to manage the filter validation. This way, the isFiltersValid function will only be called when the filters change, and it won't be triggered on every re-render. Here's an example:


import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

// Custom hook to validate filters
const useFilterValidation = (filters, isFiltersValid) => {
  const [areFiltersValid, setAreFiltersValid] = useState(false);

  const validateFilters = useCallback(() => {
    setAreFiltersValid(isFiltersValid(filters));
  }, [filters, isFiltersValid]);

  useEffect(() => {
    validateFilters();
  }, [filters, validateFilters]);

  return areFiltersValid;
};

const MyComponent = ({ filters }) => {
  const areFiltersValid = useFilterValidation(filters, isFiltersValid);

  const { data, error } = useQuery('fetchData', queryFn, {
    enabled: areFiltersValid,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => console.log('Re-render')}>Re-render</button>
      {/* Render your data or error */}
    </div>
  );
};




In custom hook also, it ends up in using a state? Can it be done without state?

There are 2 simple ways you can do in react-query:

Use the useQuery hook, this hook provides 1 parameter (optional) enabled, queryFn is only executed when the condition in enabled is satisfied
const useGetProgress = (data: any) => {
const {
    data: progress,
    isFetching: isProgressFetching,
    isLoading: isProgressLoading,
    refetch: refetchProgress,
    error: progressError
} = useQuery<any, any>({
    queryKey: ['useGetProgress', data],
    queryFn: () => {
        return api(API_URLS.STUDENT.GET_PROGRESS(data));
    },
    enabled: !!data?.path?.student_token
});
return {
    progress: progress?.data?.progresses || [],
    isProgressFetching,
    isProgressLoading,
    refetchProgress,
    progressError
};

};

You can use the useMutation hook, this way you will control where you call the api and what condition is satisfied (unlike useQuery which will be automatically called again when the queryKey parameter changes)
const useInsertDormitory = () => {
const { mutateAsync: insertDormitory, isPending: isPendingInsertHealthInsurance } = useMutation<
    unknown,
    DataError,
    any
>({
    mutationFn: (data: any) => {
        return api(API_URLS.DORMITORY.INSERT_DORMITORY(data));
    },
});
return {
    insertDormitory,
    isPendingInsertHealthInsurance
};

};


Which one you use will depend on the case but most GET methods will use useQuery.
